# Declare my own annotaion

Tags: java, spring

As you know when I want to inject a class to my class's property in spring framework I do something like this:

```
Class sample {
  @Autowired 
  MyService service;
}
```

or use @Resource or @Named or  what else.
but now I wonder that if possible I declare my own annotation like @MyInjection to do this stuff and besides do something more.

for example, instead of searching the application context and find proper bean to inject, create a class and inject this created bean to property of class.

Thanks.

Comment: You can, but you'll need to write your own `BeanPostProcessor` as well.

Comment: @juan.facorro I think the point was how to get the behavior rather than declaring an annotation.

Comment: @juan.facorro It is not the duplicate of that since we have Spring as context here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and AdamArold I think you are both right.

Comment: Ok that's a good point how can I or where can I get the proper document or source code about the behavior of spring framework with annotations like @Autowired or ...

Comment: Thanks  Sotirios Delimanolis, I handle it with BeanPostProcessot and some snipped Java reflection.

Answer (score 1):

An **annotation** is just basically data about data. So if you want something to **handle** your annotation you have to write a custom annotation processor.

I suggest you should look into Spring's AOP features for more details:

[Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-introduction)

With AOP you basically create an annotation (in your case) then you configure Spring to do *something* when it bumps into your annotation (Spring uses regexps for this if I remember it right). This is called a *Pointcut*. Then if Spring finds a match it runs your custom code which can be basically anything.

Comment: Note that Spring AOP only has method invocation joinpoints. They seem to want to set fields.

Comment: as Sotirios Delimanolis said correctly AOP only has method invocation jointpoints and I want to set fields.

Comment: I assumed that you call setters if you want to set fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want could be achieved by using Spring's **factory method**, which gets called when Spring is about to resolve some dependency. [See example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) Hope this helps.